# Does NSSortDescriptor can sort array with DateTime type?

Tags: iphone

Here is my code:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"inspectionDateTime"
                                                 ascending:YES];


NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
sortedArray = [listAllProject sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

[sortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
 {
     UDS_ProjectField *projectField1 = obj1;
     UDS_ProjectField *projectField2 = obj2;


     return [projectField1.inspectionDateTime compare:projectField2.inspectionDateTime];
     return  YES;
 }];
```

I use this to sort an array of a table in database which has field name "inspectionDateTime"
type DATETIME, but the result is not correct.

This is the result

15/2/12
15/1/12
12/3/12

but expecting result is
12/3/12
15/2/12
15/1/12

So the question is NSSortDescriptor can sort DateTime type, if not please show me another way

Comment: But I get the wrong result

Answer (score 0):

NSSortDescriptor can be used to date sorting, I used following code and it is working for me:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey::@"inspectionDateTime"
ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)];
[listAllProject sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [listAllProject sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
 {
     UDS_ProjectField *projectField1 = obj1;
     UDS_ProjectField *projectField2 = obj2;


     return [projectField1.inspectionDateTime compare:projectField2.inspectionDateTime];
     return  YES;
 }];
```

For more you can read [docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSComparator)